# Second monitor, image shifted after auto adjusting

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce

I use LP2250p Wide as a second monitor. The GP is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560 Ti and the OS is Windows 10. Right after connection everything was fine, but than I accidently hit "Auto adjustment" button on the monitor and the image shifted to the right and a vertical black strip (about 15 cm wide) appeared at the left part of the monitor.

I've tried some solutions, but they did not help: to update drivers, change resolution, shift image using monitor menu (in its most left position the black strip is still 8-9 cm wide), sift image using Nvidia Control Panel (image went inside black strip, but its border did not move).
I believe, the problem is in "Auto adjustment", since after changing resolution to the minimal (800*600) and changing update rate to 60Hz it was fine for a moment, but than "Auto adjustment" appears (this time without me hitting the button) and the image became shifted again.

So my question is: is it possible to somehow turn off automatic "Auto adjustment"? Or maybe there is some other solution, please?

Comment: Don’t use a VGA connection if at all possible. // When using Auto Adjust, did you make sure to have clearly defined high-contrast edges in all four sides of the image? Otherwise, the function cannot work properly.

Comment: @DanielB unfortunatelly, I do not remember. I hit Auto Adjust accidently, when was trying to reduce brightness. Ok, thanks, it seems I have no choice but to find DVI.

Comment: Auto adjust works best if the display is showing a screen without large areas that have the same color. Just open an image with high details and perform auto adjust again. That should correct the problem.

Comment: @Robert I set this image [link](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_xmTzO3Zx0ZQ/TS9Qk69ddII/AAAAAAAAHSQ/G7LSwenK4kY/s1600/67b8e0327055fffeeeabd52cfdf398b7.jpg) as a wallpaper and perform auto adjust again. Did not help.

Comment: Te linked image is pretty small. I would recommend to use an image that has the same dimension as the resolution you have configured in Windows respectively the native resolution of the monitor (1680 x 1050 for the LP2250p). And you should really consider using the DVI input instead of VGA. Driving a digital display with analoge signals is a bad idea.